# Android - Best Async Task implementation for suggestion Apis

Tags: android, rest, search, android-asynctask

I'm working with word suggestion Apis such that of google using Rest Api, so probably the normal scenario will be getting input from a user and listening to text changed and after each change call the suggestion apis to get suggested results, this also means if i wrote 10 letter , that i would have 10 Async Tasks running in the background , which is probably not efficient and putting a decent load in the background , what would be a better way to implement this so that i could handle background tasks better and get better results?

Comment: well, you wanna abort the previous ones, don't you? and/or introduce some delay

Comment: @keyser
well i actually thought of that but if you think of it as user experience it will still be not the best way around , can you specify what's in your mind?

Comment: well user experience-wise you want to discard suggestions for the first 9 letters, right?

Comment: @keyser
yes and no......
pros: abort the 9 task that would have run in the background....
cons:no real time results
the specific result or qurey the user maybe seeking maybe in the server response result of the letter index of the 5th letter  , so what if he was writing something big and he is typing fast?